# react styled components order issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

i'm making button using react and styled-components. i made 3 buttons in line and they should have `margin-left : 1rem` each other.

so i made `Button.js` component which get props(size, color) from `App.js`.

The size value consists of `large`, `medium`, and `small` values, and if one of them is specified, a button is generated in the appropriate size.

If you select one of the colors defined in `palette`, the value of the color changes to the color that suits it.

```
const palette = {
  blue: "#228be6",
  gray: "#adb5bd",
  pink: "#f06595",
};
```

I divided these factors into "sizeStyles" and "colorStyles", respectively.

```js
const sizeStyles = css`
 
  ${({size}) => css`
    height: ${sizes[size].height};
    font-size: ${sizes[size].fontSize}
  `}
```

```js
const colorStyles = css`
  ${({ theme, color }) => {
    const selected = theme.palette[color];

    return css`
      background: ${selected};
      &:hover {
        background: ${lighten(0.1, selected)};
      }
      &:active {
        background: ${darken(0.1, selected)};
      }
    `;
  }}
`;
```

The Button component renders a button called `StyledButton`.

```
 <StyledButton color={color} size={size} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </StyledButton>
```

so main issue is `StyledButton`. when I write some of codes in `SytledButton` this order,

```
${colorStyles}
${sizeStyles}

  & + & {
    margin-left: 1rem;
  }
```

`margin-left:1rem` didn't apply. but If Changed order like this.

```
 & + & {
    margin-left: 1rem;
  } 

  ${colorStyles}
  ${sizeStyles}
```

it applied. Why is this happening?

here's full code of `StyledButton` just in case

```
const StyledButton = styled.button`
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  & + & {
    margin-left: 1rem;
  } 
  ${colorStyles}
  ${sizeStyles}

`;
```

Comment: Your `font-size` line is missing a semi-colon terminator. Might be relevant

Comment: wow. it was the semi-colon. It works even if i change the order after writing down the semicolon. Thank you So much!